# How do I search for a string in a MongoDB document array and project the array value in a find operation?

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I have created and inserted some simple json documents, each with an array into mongo:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6

use test
> db.sandbox.insert({ "array1" : [ "praxis a", "value b", "theory c"] })
> db.sandbox.insert({ "array1" : [ "mean d", "minimum e"] })
> db.sandbox.insert({ "array1" : [ "maximum f"] })
```

Then I searched for documents in the collection that contained an array1 value starting with the string 'field1'

```
> db.sandbox.find({"array1" : /praxis/})
```

This returned a single document, as expected:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52585223b8a783860470f07b"), "array1" : [  "praxis a",  "value b",  "theory c" ] }
```

However, what I really wanted was to only return the array1 field value that matched. So I tried to project the first matching item from the array:

```
> db.sandbox.find({"array1" : /praxis/}, {_id: 1, "array1.$": 1})
```

When I tried this, I got a strange error:

```
    error: {
        "$err" : "positional operator (array1.$) requires corresponding field in
 query specifier",
        "code" : 16352
        }
```

What I was hoping to get back was the value:

```
"field1: a"
```

What I thought I was settling for was to get back the array:

```
{ "array1: [ "praxis a", "value b", "theory c"] }
```

I would appreciate some help with the find function and how to project the value from the array using $ match...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sure looks like a bug, and is similar to [SERVER-9028](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9028).

There does seem to be a couple work-arounds, as both of these work:

```
db.sandbox.find({array1: 'praxis a'}, {'array1.$': 1})
```

OR

```
db.sandbox.find({array1: {$in: [/praxis a/]}}, {'array1.$': 1})
```

Both of these produce output of:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5258620315b3beb195f855b8"),
  "array1": [
    "praxis a"
  ]
}
```