# MongoDb not registering field in query specifier

Tags: regex, mongodb

Im querying a mongodb collection and only retriving a subdocument like this:

```
db.Category.find({"Children.Url" : "www.myurl.com"}, {"Children.$" : 1})
```

But when trying to run a similar query but with regex :

```
db.Category.find({"Children.Url" : /myurl/i}, {"Children.$" : 1})
```

I get this error:

```
error: {
"$err" : "positional operator (Children.$) requires corresponding field in query specifier",
"code" : 16352
}
```

Why is it not registering that the corresponding field is actually specified when using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [**Jira SERVER-9028**](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9028) issue. A workaround is:

```
db.Category.find({"Children": {$elemMatch: {Url: /myurl/i}}}, {"Children.$": 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in mongodb and also previously answered here : [How do I search for a string in a MongoDB document array and project the array value in a find operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325928/how-do-i-search-for-a-string-in-a-mongodb-document-array-and-project-the-array-v)

Modifying the query like this gives expected results:

```
db.Category.find({"Children.Url" : {$in : [/myurl/i]}}, {"Children.$" : 1})
```